# Access 2010 update date field based on another field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm relatively new to Access and VBA but I have managed to get some basic VBA tricks working in both Access and Excel. Now I've got a challenge that I can't seem to crack. I'm building a database to track maintenance of a small trucking fleet. I've got most of the tables and forms I need to do the basic tracking and management of equipment and maintenance in place.

One of the things we're tracking is called PM's which stands for preventative maintenance (lube jobs and oil changes). We do those on calendar intervals for trailers and mileage intervals for tractors. Right now, I'm trying to get the calendar tracked equipment working. I've a table called tblEquipmentMaster which is where all the specifics for each piece of equipment is kept (make, model, year, VIN, etc) and that table has a field called LastPMDate. All the maintenance records go in two other tables, tblMaintenance which records the unit number, vendor, invoice date and invoice amount and tblMaintenanceDetails which records the each line item of work that was performed on the unit (i.e. replaced water pump, replaced headlight etc).

The maintenance details table also contains a drop down list of standard maintenance codes to allow for easier searching of certain maintenance items later. One of those codes is PM. I also have several forms built to interact with these tables including a data entry form for adding new maintenance records.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the LastPMDate field for any unit number in tblEquipmentMaster automatically update to match the InvoiceDate field in tblMaintenance anytime an invoice is entered for that unit number which has a line item containing the code PM.

I've tried building an update query to do this but in addition to changing the LastPMDate field like I want it to, it also ends up changing the invoice dates for all previous PM invoices to the date of the last invoice which contained a PM. Not good.

So my question is, would an update query be the best way to do this or would I be better off with some sort of VBA solution? I have an add record button on my maintenance invoice data entry form which users use as a save record/clear form button when all the info for an invoice has been entered. I'm thinking some VBA code tied to the on_click of that button which would look at the invoice you just added, determine if it contains the PM maintenance code, then update LastPMDate field for that unit number with invoice date from that invoice would be a good way to do it but I honestly have no idea what functions or methods I'd need to get that to work.

Any insights or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You question unfortunately is not the easiest to understand. I'd suggest breaking it down to a minimal example of the problem as it seems most of the background info is not needed to reproduce it. These probably confuse more than they help.

Comment: You said 'tblMaintenance which records the unit number', yet you didn't mention a 'unit number' being in table 'tblEquipmentMaster'. How are those two tables related?

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to follow the flow of what you are describing, even if I have experience of PM and AM (Autonomous maintenance).
What is lacking is the relations between the three tables. 
Nevertheless I prefer VBA solutions (maybe because I started programming when everything had to be written...). With VBA you can finely control your workflow.

If I understood well the 1st table is tblMaintenance in which you have the Invoice data. 
Then you should have to scan the tblMaintenanceDetails to find the list of PMs and filter the tblEquipmentMaster with current PM value to update the LastPMDate with the date of the 1st table.

Did I succeed in providing you an idea to solve your problem?

Let me know.